# Return solutions as decimal instead of exact value in sympy

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy

I am using sympy to solve the following three equations:

```
t(x-40cos(70))=-300cos(40)
t(y-40sin(70))=300sin(40)
x^2+y^2=250^2
```

I have this line of code that returns me the solutions:

```
print(nonlinsolve([Eq(x*t-40*t*cos(70), -300*cos(40)),
                   Eq(y*t-40*t*sin(70), 300*sin(40)),
                   Eq(x**2 + y**2, 250**2)],
                   [x, y, t]))
```

However, the values it returns are in exact form:

```
FiniteSet((10*(sqrt(-16*sin(70)**2*cos(40)**2 - 16*sin(40)**2*cos(70)**2 - 32*sin(40)*sin(70)*cos(40)*cos(70) + 625*cos(40)**2 + 625*sin(40)**2)*cos(40) + 4*sin(40)*sin(70)*cos(40) + 4*sin(40)**2*cos(70))/(cos(40)**2 + sin(40)**2), 10*(-sqrt(-16*sin(70)**2*cos(40)**2 - 16*sin(40)**2*cos(70)**2 - 32*sin(40)*sin(70)*cos(40)*cos(70) + 625*cos(40)**2 + 625*sin(40)**2)*sin(40) + 4*sin(40)*cos(40)*cos(70) + 4*sin(70)*cos(40)**2)/(cos(40)**2 + sin(40)**2), 30*sqrt(-16*sin(70)**2*cos(40)**2 - 16*sin(40)**2*cos(70)**2 - 32*sin(40)*sin(70)*cos(40)*cos(70) + 625*cos(40)**2 + 625*sin(40)**2)/(-625 + 16*cos(70)**2 + 16*sin(70)**2) + 120*(-sin(40)*sin(70) + cos(40)*cos(70))/(-625 + 16*cos(70)**2 + 16*sin(70)**2)), (10*(4*sin(40)*sin(70)*cos(40) + 4*sin(40)**2*cos(70) - sqrt(-16*sin(70)**2*cos(40)**2 - 16*sin(40)**2*cos(70)**2 - 32*sin(40)*sin(70)*cos(40)*cos(70) + 625*cos(40)**2 + 625*sin(40)**2)*cos(40))/(cos(40)**2 + sin(40)**2), 10*(4*sin(40)*cos(40)*cos(70) + 4*sin(70)*cos(40)**2 + sqrt(-16*sin(70)**2*cos(40)**2 - 16*sin(40)**2*cos(70)**2 - 32*sin(40)*sin(70)*cos(40)*cos(70) + 625*cos(40)**2 + 625*sin(40)**2)*sin(40))/(cos(40)**2 + sin(40)**2), 120*(-sin(40)*sin(70) + cos(40)*cos(70))/(-625 + 16*cos(70)**2 + 16*sin(70)**2) - 30*sqrt(-16*sin(70)**2*cos(40)**2 - 16*sin(40)**2*cos(70)**2 - 32*sin(40)*sin(70)*cos(40)*cos(70) + 625*cos(40)**2 + 625*sin(40)**2)/(-625 + 16*cos(70)**2 + 16*sin(70)**2)))
```

How can I get it to return answers in decimal form?

Answer (score 0):

You can use evalf. It's a bit fiddly though because the set and tuple objects don't have the evalf method so:

```
>>> [tuple(s.evalf() for s in si) for si in sol]                                                                                          
[(-168.048969910891, -185.093337837666, -1.03464484562728), (165.411705775208, 187.453907914815, 1.42834762919956)]
```

Comment: Something a bit strange, when I use this line of code: ```nonlinsolve([Eq((y-40*sin(math.radians(70)))/(x-40*cos(math.radians(70))), -tan(math.radians(40))), Eq(x**2 + y**2, 250**2)], [x,y])``` I get answers in decimal form. Would you have any idea why?

Comment: The math module uses float and sympy expressions auto-evaluate for most float inputs.